# Environment still acting up

Tags: 16.04, xfce, proxy, desktop-environments, xfce4-terminal

I tried running some code to reset my proxy:

```bsh
if [ $(id -u) -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "This script must be run as root";
  exit 1;
fi

gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'none' ;

grep PATH /etc/environment > lol.t;
cat lol.t > /etc/environment;

printf "" > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/95proxies;

rm -rf lol.t;
```

and it messed with my desktop environment. I made prior post about this and another user said I had some of my home files owned by root. I took their advice and put the permissions back, using:

```
sudo chown -R user:user ~/
```

But even after that, my background is the only thing that loads after logging in.
I'm using Xubuntu 16.04 with xfce desktop.

Comment: What you can do is possibly share what code you run, tell us your ubuntu and desktop environments, how you figured out it was a permissions issue and then how you 'put the permissions back', do you get any error messages? We need more details, as much as you can get us.

Comment: I believe the mistake was in this command `sudo chown -R user:user ~/` it should have been `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/`

Comment: I put that in my tty2 console, but I have no new results. My computer is also saying that I'm denied permission from my /etc/environment

Comment: I took a closer look at the code I used for the proxy, and I think I might have changed my environment's name to 'lol.t' and then deleted it

Comment: Edit the question and include the new error. No the code does not rename and then delete /etc/environment

Comment: It was just a hunch I had because '/etc/environment' was next to 'lol.t' and 'lol.t' gets deleted. I put /etc/environment in the console it said 'permission denied' and it's not drive, so it said 'no such directory' when cd was used.